# Keras XOR not training

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

We have been trying for a while to get this to work. This is probably the easiest example to create and so now we need help. We've been changing the number of epochs in the fit function and that's giving us different results, but never anything good, and when we increase them too much they will always converge on 0.5.

```
#%%

inputValues = numpy.array([[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]])
inputResults = numpy.array([[0],[1],[1],[0]])

print(inputValues)
print(inputResults)
#%%

model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(2,)),
    keras.layers.Dense(units=2, activation=("relu")),
    keras.layers.Dense(units=2, activation=("softmax"))
    ])

model.compile(loss = keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(), optimizer = tensorflow.optimizers.Adam(), metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(inputValues, inputResults, epochs=2500)
model.summary()

print(model.weights)
#%%

print(model.predict_proba(inputValues))

print("End of file.")
```

From my understanding of ANN's we should have 2 inputs in the first layer, specifically for the XOR example. And two outputs for the output (either a 0, or a 1). I assume that since it is not required to say what these outputs are (0 or 1), tensor flow is dealing with this automatically by comparing the results in the fit function? Lastly, we have tried with both a hidden layer (of 2) and without and still don't seem to get any better results.

Could someone let us know what we have done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is essentially a binary classification problem, because the output can be either 0 or 1. For this you don't need two ouput neurons; one will do, with a sigmoid function that will return either a 0 or a 1 as output (sigmoid generally works well for binary classification, because its characteristic S-shape will get you values either close to 0 or close to 1).

Another adjustment you need to make is to set the loss function to binary crossentropy; your choice, sparse categorical crossentropy, is suitable for classifications into more than 2 categories.

So the code that I tried is:

```
model = keras.Sequential([
keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(2,)),
keras.layers.Dense(units=4, activation=("sigmoid")),
keras.layers.Dense(units=1, activation=("sigmoid"))
])

model.compile(loss = keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=False), optimizer = optimizers.Adam(), metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(inputValues, inputResults, epochs=2500)
```

With these settings I got training accuracy to 1.0000. It took a while to get there, and I suppose that could be sped up by playing around with the learning rate, but it should be enough to get the job done.

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me, I tried it with your settings and this worked great. Could you explain why you used a hidden layer of size 4 though?

Also could you explain why the output only needs one unit? If I was to for whatever reason add an extra output somehow, how should I define how many outputs are needed? Is it just that because the output is a float it can always be a single value?

Comment: As for the hidden layer of 4: That was just a matter of trying out different settings, and 4 worked well. In machine learning, there's always a lot of trial-and-error involved in finding the best model architecture. As for the output neuron: I's the usual approach for binary classification to have one output neuron whose output can be either 0 or 1, corresponding to the two possible categories; you'd have one output neuron per possible outcome for non-binary classification. In this case it's even more self-suggesting because the model is learning binary logic, where truth values can be 0 or 1.